# Ubuntu clock jumps but time is kind of correct

Tags: ubuntu, time, clock

My Ubuntu server

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
Linux lab01 6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Mar 12 10:22:43 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Uses `timedatectl` to sync time

I can't understand why but clock jumps a lot (like it counts super fast, it figures out the time is wrong, and kind of jumps back)

this are two `date` commands with 1s between them

```
lab@lab01:~$ date
Mon Mar 25 02:25:24 PM CET 2024
lab@lab01:~$ date
Mon Mar 25 02:25:03 PM CET 2024
```

sudo `timedatectl timesync-status` shows a high jitter and offset values (tens of seconds) but I can't understand why

```
    Server: 162.159.200.1 (0.pool.ntp.org)
Poll interval: 32s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)
         Leap: normal
      Version: 4
      Stratum: 3
    Reference: A0E080C
    Precision: 1us (-25)
Root distance: 9.864ms (max: 5s)
       Offset: -22.284696s
        Delay: 3.924ms
       Jitter: 10.223410s
 Packet count: 53
    Frequency: +0.000ppm
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you correlate the "figuring out the time is wrong and kinda jumping back" with the points where timedatectl runs? As in, is the speeding up happening between the points where the system checks its internal time against the external source? What sort of computer is this? Does it have a battery  (laptop) or is it a desktop that may have a CMOS battery? If it is a desktop and has a button battery on the mainboard, have you replaced this button battery?

Comment: @music2myear It's a desktop pc with an ubuntu server on. I've recently changed the button battery with a new one but still, no luck with my issue. "As in, is the speeding up happening between the points where the system checks its internal time against the external source" how can I check it?

Comment: I don't know how timedatectl works, but I'd guess it checks at regular or possibly defined intervals. So you look at its logging and correlate the "jumps" you are observing.

Comment: @music2myear I think they're the Poll interval but again, don't know how it checks it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small fix on the grub make it works again

In the `/etc/default/grub` file you must add `tsc=nowatchdog` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

Save and reboot and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Are you running inside of a virtual machine?   If so, this is likely the root of your clock jump.   Virtual clocks "float" compared to the system clock.  Depending upon how busy the virtual machine and the underlying host machine is this float can result in the virtual machine clock drifting from the physical clock.  Periodically this will have to be resynchronized and this results in a "clock jump" within the virtual machine.

I ran into this years ago when PC virtualization began to appear because I was working in an area where high precision timing was required.   I noticed data sets from virtual machines had very different characteristics on timing records generated on them from physical machines.  The root of this problem turned out to be the floating system clock in the virtual machine re-synching, and "jumping" while a subset of the timed events were open.  On the physical hardware the clock didn't jump, so the physical machines had data sets that had smaller standard deviations, lower maximums (and averages, and medians, and,....)

Comment: No, it's bare metal